# Can't add AjaxToolkit Control to User Control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, vb.net-2010

I have a simple user control and I want to add an AjaxToolkit control to it. The one I want is the ModalPopupExtender, but the same thing happens no matter which AjaxToolkit control I choose. When I drag and drop the control onto the Source page instead of appending the @Register line and the  tags I get a whole bunch of xml type code starting with

```
<soap-env:envelope soap-env:encodingstyle="........
```

I have even tried manualy typing in an @Register line adding ToolkitScriptManager line and then a ModalPopupExtender and no joy.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: does it work in your webpages and not working in user controls? Or you introduced Ajax control toolkit for the first time in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Praveen Correct only happened in UserControl (ascx file)... I tried fixing first by doing a clean. This did not help. I then closed VS2010 and cleared the ReflectedSchemas directory and this fixed the issue.